# Preparing a separatable list of Q&A using R and latex (or markdown)

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, r-markdown

I am relatively new the knitr / markdown world, but really want to use it for my work.

We have to prepare a large number of question papers in R, and a corresponding set of solution handouts with answers.

We don't want to keep two separate documents, one for just questions, and another one for questions+answers. I want to just keep the questions + answers in one document.

Is there a way using Sweave or knitr or markdown, so that we can just extract the questionnaire when needed? (The solution handout will be the original document.)

The format is flexible. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try using a custom hook with `if(before && print_answers_variable)` - http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks

Comment: You might want to look into LaTeX packages for this, of which there are many (start perhaps, with the `exam` document class).